# Testing a web application cluster with spring and junit

Tags: spring, tomcat, testing, junit

Our team is fairly new to testing.
We have created tons of junit tests they are all running on our local machines.
Now, we have a staging machine which is comprised of 10 different machines (from mysql server to mongodb replication set) we would like to run our junit on the staging cluster ( a cluster of 3 apache tomcats with load balancer)

Whats our best way of doing that? is it possible to initiate the junit tests in a remote way? (lets say from our local machine to trigger the junit on the remote staging cluster)?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an integration test not an Unit test. You can look at using Selenium ( if its UI based ) or you can use FitNesse ( allows you to test without UI) . Alternatively you can use cargo to bring up all the 3 tomcats in an integrated fashion and then run your tests using  TestNG